# How to debug this Python 3.7 syntax error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm still trying to learn Python as much as I can. I came across this [project](https://towardsdatascience.com/finding-a-grocery-delivery-slot-the-smart-way-f4f0800c4afe) and I though it is probably a bit over-ambitious to use it to learn from and I was right. For a start it outputs this error

```
available_list = [f'\n{key} - {value}' for (key, value) in slot_data.items() if value != 'UNAVAILABLE']
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

and already have no idea how to fix it. I'm stuck as I have no idea what `f'\n{key}` is in line 50 of code. What is it supposed to be?

### Update

Thanks to the people who responded. But now I have a new error. I added

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

To check Python version as someone suggested.

```
3.7.5 (default, Nov 20 2019, 09:21:52) 
[GCC 9.2.1 20191008]
<Response [400]>
{}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Documents/Python works/get-grocery-delivery-slots.py", line 47, in <module>
    for slot_day in r.json()['data']['slot_days']:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 897, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 518, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 370, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
    return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: It appears that the python version is <3.5

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're trying to use a [f-string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) which is only supported on Python 3. The closest Python 2 equivalent would be something like this:

```
'\n{key} - {value}'.format(key=key, value=value)
```

Alternatively:

```
'\n{} - {}'.format(key, value)
```

Comment: Thanks I thinks it now has a new error i have no idea about

Comment: If I managed to solve the original problem, please mark it as solved and ask a new question if needed.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the kind people on here i fixed it by changing the first line to `#!/usr/bin/python3.7`